# Including Command Line Scripts with an R Package

Tags: r, package, rscript, r-package

I am interested in providing a command line interface to an R package called Slidify that I am authoring. It uses `Rscript` and I think that would make it cross-platform. The scripts are stored in the subdirectory `inst/slidify`. In order to use the script from any directory, I added its path to my `.bash_profile` as I am on a Mac.

My question is

1. How should I handle installation of the script in an automated cross-platform way?
2. How can I make sure that the file permissions are retained in this process?
3. What should the shebang line for the script be? I am currently using

   `#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla --slave`

I would appreciate pointers on how to handle this and any examples of R packages that already do it. Just to make sure, I am clear on how this would work, a user would be able to generate a slide deck from `slides.Rmd` by just running `slidify generate slides.Rmd` from the command line.

UPDATE:

Here is how I install it on a Mac from the command line. I use the excellent [sub](https://github.com/37signals/sub) library by 37 signals to create the scripts.

`echo "$(path/to/clidir/slidify init -)" >> ~/.bash_profile
exec bash`

Two follow up questions

1. Can I package these commands into an R function `install_slidify_cli`?
2. How can I mirror these commands for Windows users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lovin' `slidify` so would be glad to help.

But in short, you can't.

R packages simply cannot install outside of `$R_HOME` or the chosen library folder.  Ship the script in the package, and tell users to copy it.  If there was a better way, out [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) package with predecessor / alternative to `Rscript` would long have used it, and `roxygen` / `roxygen2` would also have shipped something.

Comment: I believe `pgfSweave` used to provide such a script, but [apparently](https://github.com/cameronbracken/pgfSweave/commit/cea3c877827bc1a7b7b4e47548ee43fc4b75c814) they later decided it was against the rules to install it automatically.

Comment: They did, and it was *horrible*. At the time I was still running the `cran2deb` autobuilder and it gave me fits. Total cowboy style, totally crazy.  Luckily someone else told them off :)

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel I have updated my question with details on how I install the cli from the command line. I would appreciate your thoughts on the two follow up questions raised.

Comment: Dunno. Re 1), I keep `~/bin/` in my path would just softlink from there.  Lots of options, and no idea about 2) as that is pretty hopeless territory.

Comment: Probably will keep it non-windows for now. Given the many options you indicate, what would be you recommend?

Comment: I really don't know. It's open -- maybe ask on r-devel too, or just experiment. This has not settled, and R has no mechanism for it as best as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to post a question on r-devel.

Comment: Can you "emulate" the scripts by using functions instead? Say a script takes 3 arguments, can you not just create a function taking the same 3 arguments and create a "shell" script that essentially gets the 3 arguments, loads the package and calls the function in the package with appropriate arguments?