# Is there an approach for distributing R command-line scripts with an R package?

Tags: r, command-line

According to this post:

[Including Command Line Scripts with an R Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434543/including-command-line-scripts-with-an-r-package)

There is no recommended (or even good) approach to distributing R scripts meant to run from the command line (outside R) in an R package.  Has that changed?  If not, what approaches might make the most sense to match command-line scripts with packaged code?

Comment: You're not supposed to re-ask existing questions on Stack Overflow. If you would like to see if things have changed since a question was answered, you may add a bounty to the old question so it gets more attention. However, nothing has changed with how R is meant to be run that would change the answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment answered my question. I'll consider a bounty for future questions along similar lines--thanks for the hint.